# How to wrap different type of object in one single wrapper object

Tags: java

i have a condition where i need to use a fixed Method signature which may accept different type of object. one solution i think is to use a super class and let all as a subclasses. however is there any good elegant design pattern kind of solution where we solve this

also once method gets an object of certain type can we know the type of instance without instanceof check ?
please suggest.

Comment: Not enough context. What is that method's signature, for instance? Also, you don't really use a _method_ (or are you talking about a `Method` instance?), but an interface or abstract class or...

Comment: why is it not elegant enough? you could use an interface too, if it's appropriate

Comment: what do these objects have in common?

Comment: As fge says, we need more information. Generally speaking if you're coming up against this type of problem then you may just be thinking about the problem incorrectly. If you need to accept different types of object, there's almost certainly some common denominator between them.

Comment: Are you sure you need this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_Principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little bit vaque, and can be interpreted in two different ways:

**Implementing different behavior in one class**

Let's assume you have two different classes: `Cat` and `Dog`. Then you have a class `Animals` and want to do something like this:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
Dog dog = new Dog();

Animals animals = new Animals();
animals.feed(cat);
animals.feed(dog);
```

Here `feed()` executes different code, depending on the parameter type:

```
public class Animals {
    public void feed(Cat cat) {
        // ... feed the cat
    }

    public void feed(Dog dog) {
        // ... feed the dog
    }
}
```

This is called [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

**Implementing different behavior in different classes**

On the other hand, you could define an interface `Pet` which provides a method, let's say `eat()`:

```
public interface Pet {
    void eat();
}
```

Then `Cat` and `Dog` should implement `Pet` to get different behavior:

```
public class Cat implements Pet {
    public void eat() {
        //...
    }
}

public class Dog implements Pet {
    public void eat() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then your class `Animals` would look like this:

```
public class Animals {
    public void feed(Pet pet) {
        pet.eat();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example . i like to use this having interface only with polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

Implementing an interface is a better *pattern* than inhering a super class. in that way your classes retain their one-inheritance capacity.

regarding the other question about `instanceOf`, there is rarely a genuine need to determine the actual class of the object. you can always resort to polymorphism. put all methods that you need to invoke on the object in the interface itself. in that way you will never need to know the actual type.